# Craft 3 Element Api when system status is disabled

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi, system-status

- Using Craft 3 RC14
- System status is set to off

Wondering if anyone has approached the same problem as I did. If there is a way to use **element api** while the system status is disabled?

I have tried to check the app's status within the element api using `\Craft::$app->isSystemOn` and it does display **true** when the status is enabled, on the other hand it doesn't even go to the element.api and returns 503.

I have to keep the status disabled as during the development I don't want any search engine to crawl the content of the website before the actual launch date.

Is there way to set the status on the api end or any other solution that would make my api active while the website is disabled?

Comment: Any reason you can't just take Craft's system status out of the picture and setup basic HTTP authorization to block crawlers? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?